# Avoiding vulnerable indirect dependency with yarn

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I am a Rails dev, and somewhat new to JS dependency management. I manage JS dependencies with yarn/webpacker, although I don't think there's anything webpack/webpacker-specific about this question.

Recently Github alerted me to a vulnerability it found in my yarn dependencies for a GH repo.

```
Upgrade lodash to version 4.17.13 or later. For example:
   lodash@^4.17.13:
      version "4.17.13"
```

(CVE-2019-10744)

I don't have lodash as a *direct* dependency, it's not mentioned in my `package.json`.

Rather it is an indirect/transitive dependency -- some of my dependencies (or their dependencies) depend on lodash. Actually several of them.

My `yarn.lock` contains this:

```
"lodash@>=3.5 <5", lodash@^4.0.0, lodash@^4.17.11, lodash@^4.17.4, lodash@~4.17.10:
  version "4.17.11"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.11.tgz#b39ea6229ef607ecd89e2c8df12536891cac9b8d"
  integrity sha512-cQKh8igo5QUhZ7lg38DYWAxMvjSAKG0A8wGSVimP07SIUEK2UO+arSRKbRZWtelMtN5V0Hkwh5ryOto/SshYIg==
```

Which I think means there are 5 things in my dependency tree that want lodash. One of them allows lodash 3.5 and 4.x, the other four allow various ranges of 4.x.

I think they all would allow 4.17.13 without a conflict, but none require it.

And indeed the currently used lodash is 4.17.11, which is less than 4.17.13, and thus according to github (and the CVE), a vulnerable version.

I'm confused about the correct way to deal with this, and upgrade my lodash.

Manually adding `lodash` to my package.json just seems wrong to me -- it's not actually a dependency I care about, it's just an indirect/transitive dependency. If I add it explicitly to my package.json, I might add a version that works fine now, but conflicts with some future parts of a dependency tree. It seems like unnecessary restriction.

But is that the best practice, what I'm "supposed" to do?

I sort of thought that `yarn upgrade lodash` should update the `yarn.lock` without touching the `package.json`. But `yarn upgrade lodash` doesn't change any files at all, it leaves `yarn.lock` the same.

I'm not sure if that is because `yarn upgrade` doesn't do what I expect, or there is something else in my dependency tree preventing bumping `lodash` to 4.17.13 -- but if there is, how would I discover what that is? Why wouldn't it be represented in the `yarn.lock` excerpt above? (Or is it, and I'm reading yarn.lock wrong?)

I could maybe go into `yarn.lock` manually, and edit the lodash line to say `version "4.17.13"` -- it's unclear to me if that's what yarn expects me to do. (And seems dangerous, what if I edit it to something that can't resolve with the overall dependency tree?)

I have a pretty simple `package.json`, but I'm still stumped as to what I'm supposed to do here to ensure I'm using a non-vulnerable lodash. I don't understand how yarn/npm works sufficiently to know what hole to climb down.

I'd appreciate advice from anyone who is very familiar with yarn, on the standard/best/correct/"right" way to deal with this situation.

**update** it appears there may indeed be no way to do this in yarn?? https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4986  This is baffling to me, I don't understand how yarn users do without it.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 5):

Look at [Selective version resolution](https://legacy.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/), one of the cases is exactly your:

> A sub-dependency of your project got an important security update and you don’t want to wait for your direct-dependency to issue a minimum version update.

```
{
  "resolutions": { "**/**/lodash": "4.17.13" }
}
```

Actually, I think you even can not push this into a VCS, just put it into `package.json` then `yarn install` it should generate new `yarn.lock`, then you can remove `resolutions` from `package.json` (i didn't test it, just my thought)

Comment: Aha, if they mention this use case in the docs, that does suggest it might be the solution!I worry that this allows you to (accidentally) specify a version the direct depencency says is _incompatible_, it lets you totally override it. But if the docs say this, apparently this is what they want....

Comment: When the docs say "you don’t want to wait for your direct-dependency to issue a minimum version update", is implying that they expect every package should be releasing a new version every time anything it depends upon receives a security update (and this is transitive; *everything* upstream has to), which seems awfully cumebersome and unrealistic... but apparently this is the design... odd.

Answer (score 2):

Identifying how a vulnerable dependency is introduced can easily be a nightmare.
You want to have a look at your dependency tree to identify how lodash was introduced using `yarn list` (https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/list/).

This will help you understand how you got this in the first place.

Now the second part to the problem is fixing the vulnerability. this can be achieved by using a tool like Snyk.io that will scan for your dependencies and suggest which of your direct dependencies to upgrade to inject a version of lodash that is not vulnerable.